# Kann man "frönen" mit dem Akkusativ verwenden?

Tags: verb

Im folgenden Satz aus der Filmkritik zum Film "Die Schöne und das Biest":

> ...., der (...) **ein einsames Leben frönt**, verzweifelt vor Angst, die Zauberrose könnte das letzte Blütenblatt verlieren./ *Dieses Leben genießt er also nicht.*/

*Aus dem Spiegel*

Auch inhaltlich scheint mir der Satz nicht ganz richtig zu sein

Ist dies ein Fehler oder wird man das in der Zukunft immer wieder sehen?

Comment: Das hätte vielleicht *fristet* statt *frönt* heißen sollen - dreiste Autokorrektur?

Comment: Das ist eine falsche Alternative. Etwas kann ein Fehler sein *und* man man wird es in der Zukunft immer wieder sehen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nein. "frönen" verlangt immer den Dativ.

Der Spiegel ist für vieles bekannt, aber nicht unbedingt für gutes Deutsch. Wenn dort was komisches steht, kann das oft einfach schlampiger Sprachgebrauch sein.

Comment: "... der einem einsamen Leben frönt" klingt auch nicht richtig, oder? Magst Du vielleicht noch auf den Beispielsatz  eingehen?

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Doch. »Gestern brachten wir einen Bericht über Erich, den Eremiten, **der einem einsamen Leben frönt.**« Das ist vollkommen korrekt. Das Verb »frönen« bedeutet: *»sich ausgiebig einer Beschäftigung hingeben; etwas gern und ausdauernd machen.«* Einsam zu leben kann man durchaus als Beschäftigung betrachten, daher ist auch die Wahl des Wortes *»frönen«* in Ordnung.

Comment: @Marzipanherz das klingt etwas hölzern, wahrscheinlich würde niemand das sagen, aber wenigstens ist es nicht komplett falsch, im Gegensatz zu "...ein einsames Leben frönt".